# Gradle: Reading as a file works, but not as a resource

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, gradle, properties

I am able to read a file in my project resource as a plain file using the following line of code.

```
Properties props = new Properties()
File propFile = new File("src/main/resources/application.properties")
props.load(propFile.newDataInputStream())
```

But if I try to load the same using class loader in my gradle script i get null.

```
yaml.setResources(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("application.yml"));
```

Does anybody faced this issue. and How can I solve this.

Comment: Is it really the same: application.properties vs. application.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Resources under `src/*/resources` are not loaded to a gradle script class loader. You need to read it as a file or

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets.main.resources.find { it.name.equals('application.properties') }
```